# Multiple inheritance using typing module and mypy

Tags: python, types, multiple-inheritance, type-hinting, mypy

Consider the following code:

```
from typing import Union

class A:
  def function_in_a(self) -> str:
    return 'a'

class B:
  def function_in_b(self) -> str:
    return "b"

class C(A, B):
  pass

def call_functions(c: Union[A, B]) -> None:
  print(c.function_in_a())
  print(c.function_in_b())

if __name__=="__main__":
  c = C()
  call_functions(c)
```

Note that the function `call_functions` relies on definitions contained in both classes `A` and `B`. It expects objects that inherit from both of these classes.

This code will compile when run using `python test.py`. But `mypy --strict test.py` throws an error:

```
test.py:15: note: Revealed type is "Union[test.A, test.B]"
test.py:16: error: Item "B" of "Union[A, B]" has no attribute "function_in_a"
test.py:17: error: Item "A" of "Union[A, B]" has no attribute "function_in_b"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This makes sense to me. `Union` means that `c` can be a subclass of either `A` or `B`, but *not both*. I saw mention of an `Intersection` type in [PEP483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/) but a quick perusal of the `typing` module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) showed that this type was never implemented.

How can I get `mypy` to recognize that parameters of `call_functions` are objects which inherit from *both* A *and* B using type hinting?

Comment: It's currently not possible, there is an open issue to support it, the suggest workaround is to use Protocol - https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) (New in version 3.8.) to define a type that must implement both methods invoked in the function.

```py
from typing import Protocol


class A:
    def function_in_a(self) -> str:
        return 'a'


class B:
    def function_in_b(self) -> str:
        return "b"


class C(A, B):
    pass


class D(B):
    pass


class ProtoAB(Protocol):
    def function_in_a(self) -> str:
        ...

    def function_in_b(self) -> str:
        ...


def call_functions(obj: ProtoAB) -> None:
    print(obj.function_in_a())
    print(obj.function_in_b())


def main() -> None:

    c = C()
    call_functions(c)
    d = D()
    call_functions(d)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is so much more complicated than the original code. Also, I feel like this is improper use of protocols.... I'm mainly concerned with type hinting a simple case of inheriting from multiple types. There has got to be an easier way.

Comment: After digressing into the issue indicated by @daniel and looking a bit more deeply into protocols, I'm convinced this is the correct answer. Intersections are not yet implemented in the `typing` module, and the fact that Protocols can help alleviate this problem is stated explicitly in PEP544: *One can use multiple inheritance to define an intersection of protocols. If this will prove to be a widely used scenario, then a special intersection type construct could be added in future as specified by PEP 483, see rejected ideas for more details.*

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to make `A` and `B` `Protocol`. Protocols can can be used as normal class:

```
from typing import Protocol
        
class A(Protocol):
    def function_in_a(self) -> str:
        return 'a'
class B(Protocol):
    def function_in_b(self) -> str:
        return "b"
class AB(A, B, Protocol):
    pass
    
def call_functions(c: AB) -> None:
    print(c.function_in_a())
    print(c.function_in_b())

class C(A, B):
    pass
call_functions(C())
```