# Provide a variable that implements both a protocol and a common base class so it works where the base class is expected

Tags: inheritance, protocols, mypy, python-typing, python-class

There is a base class C1, a subclass C2(C1) and a protocol P1 which C2 should be compatible with. All implementations of P1 are subclasses of C1, but we can’t make C1 a base class of a protocol. Then we have a function f1 that accepts an object of type C1 as argument a1. Another function f2 has a variable v1 of type P1 (e.g. a C2, but we want to keep it generic here for possible other subclasses of C1 that implement P1) and calls function f1 with a1=v1. Mypy would fail here because v1 is not C1. How can you annotate v1 so it conforms to C1 so it can be passed to f1 as a1 without modifying f1? We can modify P1 and everything about f2 and v1.

Snippet:

```py
import typing


class C1:
  pass


class C2(C1):
  attr_1: int


class P1(typing.Protocol):
  attr_1: int


def f1(a1: C1) -> None:
  return


def f2(v1: P1) -> None:
  # v1 is always a subclass of C1
  f1(a1=v1)


f2(C2())  # C2 extends/implements both C1 and P1
```

Comment: I think for this question to be soluble we'd need more information. There are certain features of this question that hint at underlying assumptions of a specific problem like "v1 is actually a C2". Could you perhaps adapt this to contain more descriptive class/function names?

Comment: You are looking for `Intersection` type. It does not exist, consider the following dupes as possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320095/python-type-hint-intersection-of-types-class-implementing-interface, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034847/how-to-tell-mypy-that-a-class-decorator-adds-a-method-to-the-decorated-class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816264/multiple-inheritance-using-typing-module-and-mypy, plus this issue: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213

Comment: Thanks indeed it looks like the same issue as the ones you mentioned! If `Intersection` were a thing, indeed the solution would’ve been `def f2(v1: Intersection[P1, C1])`. @Mark: I clarified the wording on that part. It won’t change the situation much though. Anyway this question is answered by the referenced questions.